# Measuring distance of a colour form Picamera using a colour marker RaspberryPI

Tags: python, colors, raspberry-pi, distance, marker

Below is my current code where I’ve attempted to incorporate distance tracking in a colour detection for the colour blue in a live stream directly from the picamera and tracking it.

My University project is about designing small bots that have to locate an object in an area and retrieve it back to base. Our approach is to colour code the desired object for detection where it can track it as it moves and then be able to calculate distance to the colour as it gets closer using the picamera itself. 
When the code is run, the colour blue can be detected and tracked fine, and a distance measurement is output at the bottom corner of the frame. However, this measurement randomly fluctuates a lot and doesn't seem to be measuring to the blue marker as it doesn't respond appropriately when I move the object closer/further away from the camera.

So the issue must be that the colour marker hasn't been referenced properly in the script so that it knows to measure to that once it has used the still image "cam1.jpg" to calibrate itself (calculate focal length from) and I'm not sure on how to do this correctly. I do know that both markers (the image and the colour) have to be referenced in the same def find_marker() function but not entirely sure how. Moreover, focalLength's value depends on marker[1][0] which gets updated in the loop but focalLength doesn't which I think is where the main issue lies. I tried adding the line where I define focalLength into the loop but when When I run the script, a constant value of 0.42ft is output to the bottom of the frame meaning it's not getting updated properly and I don't know how to go about doing this due to my limited python knowledge. Below is my script where I've attempted this.

How do I reference FocalLength in the script so that its value gets updated properly in the loop?

I've been stuck on this for the past few days now and I'm still new to Python so any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated! This is as far as I've managed to get with the help of pyimagesearch's articles and online forums trying to adapt and merge pyimagesearche's blogposts for colour detection and measuring distance for my Raspberry Pi.

SPECS: Raspberry PI Zero W, python 2.7, OpenCV 3.2 on Mac via VNC  – Here’s my code:

**My code:**

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 50
camera.hflip = True
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

time.sleep(0.1)

camera.capture(rawCapture, format='bgr')
image = rawCapture.array
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)  
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)

def find_marker(image):

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)

    lower = np.array([76,31,4],dtype="uint8")
    upper = np.array([210,90,70], dtype="uint8")
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)

    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)

def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth

KNOWN_DISTANCE = 5.0

KNOWN_WIDTH = 2.0

IMAGE_PATHS = ['cam1.jpg']

image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATHS[0])
marker = find_marker(image)
focalLength = (marker[1][0] * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        image = frame.array
        blur = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))
        marker = find_marker(image)

        lower = np.array([76,31,4],dtype="uint8")
        upper = np.array([210,90,70], dtype="uint8")

        thresh = cv2.inRange(blur, lower, upper)
        thresh2 = thresh.copy()

        image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        inches = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])

        max_area = 0
        best_cnt = 1
        for cnt in contours:
                image = frame.array
                area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                if area > max_area:
                        max_area = area
                        best_cnt = cnt

        M = cv2.moments(best_cnt)
        cx,cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

        cv2.circle(blur,(cx,cy),10,(0,0,255),-1)
        cv2.putText(blur, "%.2fft" % (inches / 12),
                (image.shape[1] - 200, image.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Frame", blur)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        rawCapture.truncate(0)

        if key == ord("q"):
            break
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's kind of difficult to help advise on processing an image we can't see... you may have enough points soon to post an image if your question gets upvoted...

Comment: Hi there thanks for your response, the original image is just to calibrate the camera so it has a reference point that it can use for future calculations. The code finds the largest contour area in the image (e.g. a piece of paper stuck to a wall) and uses that for calibration in the def find_marker() function. I want to make it so when you run the script, it calibrates first, and then would apply this calibration to calculate distance to a different marker (which i want it to be the colour blue in a stream)

Comment: continued..but I don't know how to link it up correctly in syntax terms so it can do this successfully. I think the issue is that I am not updating focalLength properly because it is dependant on the value of marker[1][0] which I update in the loop but I dont update focal length as well which is where I'm going wrong. I tried adding the line defining focalLength (right before the start of the loop) into the loop but when the script is run, a constant value of 0.42ft is output to the bottom of the frame meaning its a fixed value that doesnt get updated. Any ideas how to do this? 
Thanks